# Python Pandas.to_csv unable to export columns with semicolon(;) as one column

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, but 1 of the columns contain data that is separated by a semicolon(;) during export. I am trying to export a dataframe into a csv but my csv output data keeps getting separated into the following format when opening in excel:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = { 'name' : ["a", "b"],
            'age' : [20,27],
            'tag': ["Login Location;Visit Location;Appointment Location", "Login Location;Visit Location;Appointment Location"]}

df=pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
print('done')
```

I would like to have the output in excel to be:

[image]

where the data in the tag column is intact. I've tried adding sep=',' or delimiter=',' but it still gives me the same output.

Thank you in advance,

John

Comment: How are you importing your CSV into excel? It looks like you are splitting on `;` not `,` in excel.

Comment: It's not coming from anywhere. I am adding the tag column manually and will need to have it in the format shown: Login Location; Visit Location; Appointment Location  so I can load it in another system already pre-formatted. Thanks

Comment: You should open `output.csv` in notepad or another text editor to see what `pandas` is outputting. The issue you are seeing looks like an error with how you are inspecting the data in excel.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for looking into it. Here's the output in excel 

`name,age,tag
a,20,Login Location;Visit Location;Appointment Location
b,27,Login Location;Visit Location;Appointment Location`
it contains the ; so it looks correct. But another issue I have is that I have other columns that comes after the 'tag' column. 

How do I put the contents of the tag column in quotes? single or double.

Comment: Take a look at the [`to_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). There is a `quoting` parameter that you can use. The issue you are seeing is still that your excel is configured to use `;` as a delimiter.

Comment: @Alex, thank you for the link to the documentation. I'll try to see how I can configure excel to default to `,` rather than `;`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does some stuff based on the fact that your file has a `.csv`suffix, probably using `;` as a default delimiter, as suggested in the comments.

One workaround is to use the `.txt` suffix instead:

```
df.to_csv('output.txt',index=False)
```

then open the file in Excel, and in the Text Import Wizard specify "Delimited" and comma as separator.

Do **not** pick the file in the list of previously opened files, if it's there, that won't work, you really need to do File/Open then browse the directory to find your .txt file.

Comment: Hi @joao, THanks for the guidance. The output in excel is exactly how I want it! Now the issue is that I need to save the file in `csv-utf8` format. Do you have any suggestions on how to convert it to that file format? thanks again.

Comment: When you do `Save As` in Excel just pick CSV UTF-8, it's in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alex and @joao for your inputs, this guided me to the right direction. I was able to get the output I needed by forcing excel to use `,` as the separator. By default, Excel was using tab as the delimiter, that's why it was showing me an incorrect format. Here's the link to forcing excel to use comma as a list separator: https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files